# Cannot return negative values in c

Tags: c, linux

```
int main(){ return -1; }
```

I compiled the above c program with gcc.
To find the return value of the program I used echo $?.
Output of echo $? was 255.Currently i am using terminator

how can i get negative values.

Comment: The only values you can return from `main` portably are `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`. For anything else consult your OS.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that `EXIT_SUCCESS` is equivalent to `0`.

Comment: Negative returns from main are not supported. See [**glibc**](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Exit-Status.html) "This is a value between 0 and 255 that the exiting process passes as an argument to exit."

Comment: On POSIX systems (UNIX, Linux, etc.), the value is determined by the `wait` system call. Other systems might have other semantics.

Comment: @ooga: The C standard doesn't say that `EXIT_SUCCESS == 0`; it merely says that both `0` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` denote success. But I've never heard of a system where `EXIT_SUCCESS != 0`. (I have seen systems where `EXIT_FAILURE != 1`.)

Comment: @KeithThompson I know. That's why I said "equivalent", not "equal". OpenVMS is a system where success is not equal to 0, but returning 0 from a C program will still return the success value (which I believe is usually 1, but is technically any odd value ... strange).

Comment: @ooga: Just to be pedantic (who, me?), `0` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` are not necessarily equivalent. They could denote different kinds of success. (Yes, OpenVMS was the system I was thinking of.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Good point, but I still believe that in a C program running on OpenVMS, returning `0` would be "equivalent" to returning `EXIT_SUCCESS`. If you wanted some other kind of success, you'd have to return an odd value other than 1.

Comment: @ooga: I believe that's correct, and I didn't say otherwise. What I meant was that the C standard doesn't require `0` and `EXIT_SUCCESS` to be equivalent.

Comment: @KeithThompson I believe that the standard *does* say that they are equivalent, as per 7.20.4.3: " If the value of status is zero or EXIT_SUCCESS, an implementation-defined form of the status successful termination is returned." That's exactly what I mean by saying that they are "equivalent", i.e., the implementation will return the exact same value to the OS if either EXIT_SUCCESS or 0 is returned from a C program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return code of a process is stored in a single **unsigned** byte.

You can't do that.

Comment: I think the answer would benefit immensely from being supported by some references.

Comment: if i run this program as a child of another program what will be the return value, will it be -1 or 255?

Comment: @Vivek: That depends how you interpret the byte.

Answer (score 0):

That is technically the return you wrote. The unsigned value of a byte with the signed value of -1 is 255.

Comment: that was obvious,I want to know the reason why not give out negative vaues as is

Comment: If you think it's obvious, then there's a fundamental misunderstanding here. -1 is, in binary, 11111111. 255 is 11111111 as well.